# How to Create pagination in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Hi I have implemented Pagination in PHP Code But it is not Working while clicking on the pagination links.It is displaying the same data for all the pages.Here is the code.

Controller:

```
class Testimonial extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct();
        //here we will autoload the pagination library
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }

public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('testimonial_model');
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url('testimonial/index');
    $config['total_rows'] =   $this->db->count_all("testimonials");//here we will count all the data from the table
    $config['per_page'] = 6;//number of data to be shown on single page
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
    $data["records2"] = $this->testimonial_model->get_all_testimonials($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();//create the link for pagination
    $data['mainpage'] = "testimonial";
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

Model:

```
class Testimonial_model extends CI_Model
{    
function get_all_testimonials($limit, $start)
{
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('T.*');
    $this->db->from('testimonials AS T');
    $this->db->where(array('T.status'=>1));
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}   
}
```

View:

```
<div class="pagination"><?php echo $links; ?></div>
```

Comment: Anyone who can help me this out

Comment: try with uri segmant 3 : $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

Comment: @Rijin Thank you its working

Comment: ok.. segment 1 => testimonial, 2 => index and 3 => page no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following will may help you,

```
public function index()
{
   $this->load->model('testimonial_model');
   $config = array();
   $config["base_url"] = base_url('testimonial/index');
   $config['total_rows'] =   $this->db->count_all("testimonials");//here we will count all the data from the table
   $config['per_page'] = 6;//number of data to be shown on single page
   $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
   $this->pagination->initialize($config);
   $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
   $data["records2"] = $this->testimonial_model->get_all_testimonials($config["per_page"], (($page-1)*$config["per_page"]));
   $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();//create the link for pagination
   $data['mainpage'] = "testimonial";
   $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

Comment: in first page i have 6 posts and in second page i have 2 posts For a page it should display 6 if i click on second page it is displaying the same data which is in first page.

Comment: print your query and see what you will get in start variable when you click on second page

Comment: ya tried with above code getting the same result as mine

Comment: Not getting what you are saying

Comment: have you tried by printing your query when clicking on second page?

Comment: print your query by writing $this->db->last_query(); in your model 
and check what query result you get when you click on page no. second

Comment: $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
  $this->db->select('T.*');
  $this->db->from('testimonials AS T');
  $sql=$this->db->where(array('T.status'=>1));  
  $q = $this->db->get();
  $this->db->last_query($q);
  exit();
  if($q->num_rows()>0)
  {
   return $q->result();
  }
  else 
  {
   return false;
  }          I tried this but it is displaying blank page when i execute

Comment: not need to pass any argument in function just simply past ,
$this->db->last_query()

Comment: Nothing is displaying if i pass $this->db->last_query(); displaying all the data which is in first page.

Comment: it may hide by your view so you need to put die(); and it will stop to render your view and you can see query.

Comment: Nothing it is getting displaying blank page

Comment: i hope you putted echo before this $this->db->last_query();

Comment: Executed it shown as SELECT COUNT(*) AS `numrows` FROM `testimonials` runned this query in mysql it is showing no of rows as 8

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment so I just make this an answer,

Here
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/rounded-pagination

This is what I use in making my pagination! and there is alot more of it! I also use CI as my framework!

Comment: But how can show perpage only i need to display 5 then